# mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'

Tags: amazon-athena

I am trying to create a table in AWS Athena with the following command. However I get the error:mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'

Can you helpp with this?

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'transport_evaluator_prod' (
    `messageId` STRING,
    `type` STRING,
    `causationId` STRING,
    `correlationId` STRING,
    `traceparent` STRING,
    `data` STRUCT<
    `evaluationOccurred`:STRING,
`eta`:STRUCT<
    `distance`:INT,
`timeToDestination`:INT,
`eta`:STRING,
`destination`:STRUCT<
    `latitude`:DOUBLE,
`longitude`:DOUBLE,
`altitude`:DOUBLE>,
`destinationEventId`:STRING,
`origin`:STRUCT<
    `latitude`:DOUBLE,
`longitude`:DOUBLE,
`altitude`:DOUBLE>,
`originEventId`:STRING,
`plannedArrival`:STRING,
`locationActionReference`:STRING,
`resourceUrn`:STRING,
`eventProvider`:STRING,
`occured`:STRING,
`position`:STRUCT<
    `latitude`:DOUBLE,
`longitude`:DOUBLE,
`altitude`:DOUBLE>,
`equipmentNumber`:STRING,
`received`:STRING>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
     'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION
     'for-security-pointing-to-folder'
```

Comment: Can you post few sample JSON records

Comment: Are you using nested `struct`? It is hard to understand from the above format.

Comment: Yes, I am using Nested struct @Guy :)

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy, I have tried to post the json, but the stackoverflow validation is complaining that the message is too long unfortunately.

Comment: I have now used https://www.hivetablegenerator.com/ to generate the HiveQL DDL as shown in the edited code.

Comment: Still  showing same error

Comment: you can upload to some store and share the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am providing what I changed in order to get it to work for the sake of the next person that might run into similar issues

1. I removed all quotation marks for the columns of the table as well as the inner attributes inside the 'data' struct.
2. Also watch out that all attributes under 'struct' are followed by ':'
3. Ensure that the type provided matches the one for the payload json

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the quotes from the table name:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transport_evaluator_prod (
    `messageId` STRING,
    `type` STRING,
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately didn't work

Comment: removing quotes from the table name worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue, but in my case, the problem was the name of my database. When I put the correct name, the query works.

Something like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'correct_db_name'.'transport_evaluator_prod'
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a just a bad error message that indicates there is an issue somewhere in the query that failed without generating a more specific message.  Treat it like you have to debug a query with just OK, FAIL by simplifying query until it passes, and then adding one line at a time until you see which line is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message when my table name contained `-` characters (I used the bucket name as part of the table name). When I swapped them for `_` characters the table created fine.