# Issues creating Table in Athena for overture map data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, overturemaps

I am using the queries located [here](https://github.com/OvertureMaps/data/blob/main/athena_setup_queries.sql) to try and create tables to for Overture map data. When I try and run the query below I get the error shown underneath it. I've tried a no. of answers including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499445/amazon-athena-create-external-table-mismatched-input-external-invalidrequestex) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73897478/mismatched-input-external-expecting-or-schema-table-view).

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `admins`(
`id` string,
`updateTime` string,
`version` int,
`names` map<string,array<map<string,string>>>,
`adminLevel` int,
`maritime` string,
`subType` string,
`localityType` string,
`context` string,
`isoCountryCodeAlpha2` string,
`isoSubCountryCode` string,
`defaultLanugage` string,
`drivingSide` string,
`sources` array<map<string,string>>,
`bbox` struct<minX:double,maxX:double,minY:double,maxY:double>,
`geometry` binary)
PARTITIONED BY (
`type` string)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION
's3://overturemaps-us-west-2/release/2023-07-26-alpha.0/theme=admins'


MSCK REPAIR TABLE `admins`
```

`line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'MATERIALIZED', 'OR', 'ROLE', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'`

Answer (score 0):

It's because of you are trying to run two queries in one run. If you'd put semicolons at the end of each query you would get an other error:

```
Only one sql statement is allowed. Got: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 'admins'...
```

To solve this, highlight the first query and run it, then repeat.